# In retrieving JSON data, whats the point of having a completion block return Void?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, completionhandler

So we have this function that retrieves JSON data and presents it in its completion block, what I'm trying to understand is why use the signature: `((Data) -> Void)` instead of just `(Data)`, is the `void` really necessary? Here is the function:

```
 typealias JSONData = ((Data) -> Void)


  func getJSONData(type: String, urlExtension: String, completion: @escaping JSONData) {

    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:"\(baseURL)\(type)/\(urlExtension)?api_key=\(apiKey)&region=US&append_to_response=videos,images,releases")! )


    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

      if error == nil {
        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
          switch (httpResponse.statusCode) {
          case 200:
            if let data = data {
              completion(data)
            }
          default:
            print(httpResponse.statusCode)
          }
        }
      } else {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

          if let error = error {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)") }
          return
        }
      }
    })
    dataTask.resume()
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift syntax dictates that you must declare closures with a return type after the `->`.

You have two options:

1. `typealias JSONData = (Data) -> Void`
2. `typealias JSONData = (Data) -> ()`

I see Apple using #1 most frequently.

Comment: Is it possible to omit the -> all together or is it required?

Comment: It's required. Check out https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html for more details.